# Not so expensive desktop parts (processor and gpu) recommendation

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, gaming, pc, desktop

I currently have Dell 7570 15" laptop. Upgraded with 16 GB RAM, 4 GB 940MX graphics card and i7 8th gen processor.

But still my laptop struggles in playing games at even medium settings and a very low resolution like 1024x768. Looks like this 4GB graphics card doesn't make sense.

I'm not a *gamer* but I like to play games released before 2015, especially like some of COD older games, GTA5 and CSGO. But when I play them at lower settings, I kind of miss the higher settings. I can even afford to play at 1366x768 instead of 1080p, but what I need is high quality textures, high quality grass, lights and shadows so things look more real.

I can somehow achieve this by turning off almost all high settings at playing a very low resolution, but I don't have fun then.

Now, as you know desktops and laptops and PC parts have become very expensive. I want to buy a desktop but prices are not in my budget. I had planned to buy a desktop with i5 10th gen processor and at least NVIDIA GTX 1650 or 1660 graphics (for example [this desktop](https://www.amazon.in/Lenovo-IdeaCentre-Desktop-Graphics-90N9003MIN/dp/B08DNM5HLK/ref=pd_aw_sbs_147_8?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B08DNM5HLK&pd_rd_r=c832e630-da8c-4fb5-88c3-08df9cd27bce&pd_rd_w=qJqAX&pd_rd_wg=av47H&pf_rd_p=9411a0cd-9506-4b5c-bbab-9f7b0e6a4733&pf_rd_r=B2ZK2KAEGZR942KXPX72&psc=1&refRID=G38VWG00H72TPV487VT3)). I don't have any reasons, but many people recommend at least these. But it goes 30% above my budget. And looks like these PC parts aren't going to be cheap any time soon, until 2022. My laptop really doesn't have any problem except this poor graphics card.

So my question is, is there even low hardware recommendations (Processor and Graphics card) where I can play these games with almost high settings (not ultra) and 1366x768 or 1280x720 resolution, efficiently?

Comment: I'd suggest going to the games tab on gpucheck.com selecting your desired games and seeing what frame rates certain GPU's get (roughly double the frame rates to compare 1366 resolution instead of 1080) . That said, I feel the 1660 Super or RX 590 are the sweet spot for Full HD currently. On a different track, look at the Ryzen 5 3400G CPU (the G means integrated Graphics)... you may not even need a GPU for the games you mainly play. for instance https://au.pcmag.com/sound-cards/63709/amd-ryzen-5-3400g (I believe you can add a GPU later)

Comment: @Stax the fluctuation and lags in game is affected by FPS? (Not that I play only offline games)

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by fluctuation and Lag. In my area (in Australia) Lag is mainly slow internet, and online games are... frustrating. This is different to fluctuations, which may be other bottlenecks like slow hard drive. low Ram etc. FPS is the Frames Per Second the PC can render. I.e. the "Smoothness" of the display. Most monitors do 30 FPS, and you don't want to go much below this. FYI, I came across recommended CPU for CSGO being a Pentium E5700 however the Ryzen is 3 x faster at 4 Cores, and doesn't need a GPU (to start with). FYI https://www.logicalincrements.com/games/csgo

Comment: See the "Minimum" Tier. Also FYI:https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Pentium-E5700-vs-AMD-Ryzen-5-3400G/m976vsm825156

Comment: @Stax there was a typo in my comment. I mean't I don't play online games. Just offline. lag fluctuation means game is not smooth.